# cant parse json from php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "avatar": [
    {
      "Trophies": 1022,
      "clanLevel": 1,
      "Attack K Factor": -1921682810,
      "Attacks Won": 1,
      "freeGems": -1916837036,
      "clanBadge": 0,
      "clanCaslteLevel": 5,
      "currentHomeId": 12888426248,
      "clanRole": 2,
      "exp": 5013,
      "homeId": 12888426248,
      "Attacks Lost": -1307141699,
      "clanId": 326417604098,
      "boughtGems": -1517098100,
      "userNameChange": false,
      "numOfNameChanges": 0,
      "level": 111,
      "league": 5,
      "userName": "King Shiv",
      "nameTag": 1440968203000,
      "clanName": "lol",
      "Defenses Won": 17,
      "maxCcTroops": 30,
      "gems": -1370568149,
      "Defenses Lost": -2055915376,
      "townHall": 9,
      "inWar": 1,
      "Attack Rating": -1000115629
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am trying to parse it like this:

```
$url = "http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Player?player=1;
$url = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $url);
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo "IGN: ".$data['avatar']['userName'];
echo "<br />Town Hall: ".$data['avatar']['townHallLevel'];
echo "<br />Level: ".$data['avatar']['level'];
echo "<br />Trophies: ".$data['avatar']['trophies'];
echo "<br />".$data['avatar']['clanRole'];
```

It doesn't return any values. Why is this?

It just returns:

IGN: 
Town Hall: 
Level: 
Trophies:

Comment: you forgot to close `$url` with `"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` with second parameter setting to `true` will return `Array`
`$data['avatar']` has sub array so you can access it whole sub array like

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$subarray = $data['avatar'][0];
echo $subarray['userName']; // King Shiv
```

See [**Demo**](https://ideone.com/AwaTg6)

Comment: Here is the page I am trying it on: http://forumalliance.net/api/displayPlayer.php?id=1

Comment: @ShivamPaw  This URL does not give you json data. it returns html content so, how can you decode them?

Comment: Thanks I got it now :D @sandeepsure

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Player?player=1;
                                                     //^ you forgot to close with "
                                                 //That's why it cant parse your data

$url = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $url);
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo "IGN: ".$data['avatar'][0]['userName']; // [0] here is the first index
echo "<br />Town Hall: ".$data['avatar'][0]['townHall'];
echo "<br />Level: ".$data['avatar'][0]['level'];
echo "<br />Trophies: ".$data['avatar'][0]['Trophies'];
echo "<br />".$data['avatar'][0]['clanRole'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you having a problem with the url. Tried with cURL and it returns "couldn't connect to host", which can be a firewall that blocks or something with your configuration. Your json decoding is fine, fix the problem with the address and you'll get the content.